# Wordpress WP Admin showing 404 error while other pages working fine

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

My blog is working fine and all pages are loaded properly. The only issue is with wp-admin page. It is showing 404 error.

Tried checking the permission but that did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

you remove .htaccess file from folder

Type in example.com/wp-login.php

And admin login. Then,

Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save. (just automatically recreates your .htaccess again).

If the problem persists. Try disabling plugins. Enable plugins 1 by 1 until the problem occurs again. That will narrow down the faulty plugin.